# php mysql select information from three tables from the database

Tags: php

the customer search is carried out by card number (see table A customer) and the code used by me is this:

```
$id = $_POST['card_number'];
SELECT e.*, sum(u.points) as points, sum(u.cost) as cost,
max(date_format(u.date_points, '%e/%c/%Y')) as data
FROM `customer` AS e 
    INNER JOIN `points` AS u ON e.id_customer = u.id_customer 
where card_number='$id'
```

now I expose my tables and then I explain my problem

Table A Customer:
it contains the information of the members

| id_customer | name | card_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luca | 1234567890 |
| 2 | Mark | 9876543210 |

Table B Points:
it contains the points accumulated and the cost incurred

| id_points | id_customer | points | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | 40 |
| 3 | 1 | 20 | 60 |
| 4 | 2 | 35 | 35 |

Result:

```
customer with id_customer 1 has a total of 25 points
customer with id_customer 2 has a total of 45 points
```

Table C deducted points:
it contains the points that will be deducted at the next purchase

| id_deducted | id_customer | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 15 |

Result:

```
customer with id_customer 1 straight 5 points total remaining 20 points
customer with id_customer 2 climbs 15 points, total remaining 30 points
```

my question is this how can i make the sum of points from table B - the sum of points from table c? how can i add it in the select?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single request to get all info you need, you can make subrequests like this:

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    (
      SELECT
        SUM(p.points)
      FROM
        points p
      WHERE
        p.id_customer = c.id_customer
    ) AS points,
    (
      SELECT
        SUM(d.points)
      FROM
        deducted_points d
      WHERE
        d.id_customer = c.id_customer
    ) AS deducted_points
FROM
    customer c;
```

The result would be as follows

| id_customer | name | card_number | points | deducted_points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luca | 1234567890 | 25 | 5 |
| 2 | Mark | 9876543210 | 45 | 15 |

But it would be very slow on large amounts of users and points changes I think. So I'd do select from users and then loop through them making individual requests to `points` and `deducted_points` tables.

Comment: thanks very kind, how can I subtract the result of table point B with table point C? example SUM (p.points) -SUM (d.points)

Comment: You can do it in your code

Comment: yes, sorry, my mistake

Comment: yes, sorry, my mistake